# Setting a class variable for finding current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need to find the current logged in user in my model.

I defined `cattr_accessor` `current_logged_in` in `User` model.

Now, when a user logs in I set `User.current_logged_in = current_user.id`.

Later, in other models I access the variable using `User.current_logged_in_user`. As of now it works.

Is it the right way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

A good way to implement it, unless you're just doing your code as a learning exercise is to use a plugin like [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise).

That said, you should avoid accessing the current_user in models. current_user is a session thing and should not be tied to the model. Instead pass in the current_user as a parameter to methods in the model. Something like:

```
def can_delete_item(user)
  if user.is_admin?
    ....
  else
    .....
  end
    .....
end
```

Comment: I already have a rails application . need to rewrite it to make it multi tenant .So this was a kludgy work around i thought of , inserting current_user_id with all the data i save .So that i could know which data belonged to which tenant . I just wanted to save rewriting all the .create and .new methods to include (:tenant_id => current_tenant_id ) in my controllers.